# User that run Docker health check

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have Dockerfile:

```
...
USER oracle
HEALTHCHECK CMD "$ORACLE_BASE/$CHECK_DB_FILE" >/dev/null || exit 1 
...
```

Why does healthcheck process run as root? Is it normal that some process run as root in container?

Docker version 1.13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was in that I rewrite

```
...
USER root
...
```

in child image as a result HEALTHCHECK run from root.